# Can I pipe jpegs (in a byte array format) to my server using stream (vlc)

Tags: c#, image-processing, vlc, live-streaming

I have a C# desktop app.

At present i have been doing motion detection between consequtive jpegs and if the image has changed I have then converted the 'motion' jpeg to a byte array and uploaded it to my server via WCF.

Obviously, this can be quite 'weighty' to keep up with.

So, I have been looking at streaming and encoding instead with perhaps using VLC.

I searched around and someone on this site suggested using this commandline:

```
vlc -I dummy fake:// --fake-file c:\1.jpg -vvv --sout #transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=localhost:1234}}
```

Where '--fake-file-' is a physical file on my hard drive.

This would not be ideal for me.
Is there a way to pass a byte array instead of the location to a physical file?

Comment: You obviously can't pass byte array to external executable... But it does not seem to be problem you've mentioned in the title - would you mind to clarify?

Comment: _[Large Data and Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx)_

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Hi, if the exe was run under a C# process and therefore I had access to pipes would it be possible then?

Comment: @MickyDuncan Hi, thanks for the link.  I have optimized the WCF call to use MTOM already.  Each image is around 17kb.  If I could encode the jpegs using VLC and then stream the stdout I am hoping that the number of bytes uploaded is greatly reduced

Comment: I seriously doubt you can safely pass binary data via redirected input stream - never tried myself, would not recommend - but try and see... (You can use named pipes, but it is rare for random program to accept such input - so probably not the case here).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for your reply.  There is only 1 receiving app and that is my IIS server.  I shall look into what you have said. thanks

Comment: @BobDeveloper Hi, I had a Google search but could not see what you were referring to and in what context? thanks

Comment: http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets   can you use a websocket server with node.js in your architecture?  This is an example using ffmpeg or avconv.  Maybe vlc can send to the same websocket server.